# I understand the US portion for applying for a K1 Visa - what about requirements from Russia?

Tags: marriage, visa, russia

Suppose an American citizen is engaged to a Russian citizen. The couple would like to be able to live in America together. They do not particularly need to live together in Russia, although the Russian would like to be able to return from time to time to visit family etc.

In order for the Russian to come to the US, the American needs to approve a visa for the Russian to travel to the US, where they have 90 days to get married and the Russian can file for a change of status.

The part I don't understand is, what do we need from Russia?  The Russian is obviously going to have to tell them "hey I'm going to the US to marry a guy, and I will be there indefinitely (though I am planning on coming back to visit family etc.)".

What process do they have to do on the Russian side?

Comment: I edited it to make it a request for legal information because we don't provide legal advice on this site.

Comment: You will probably get a better response at [Expatriates.SE], but I think the answer is that once she has her passport, she has no more obligation to the Russian government until she presents it to a passport inspector before she boards the plane.  Why do you think it "obvious" that she has to tell them she's going to the US to get married, or how long she plans to be out off the country?  Did you tell the US about your plans when you left the US?

Comment: @phoog, very good comment, and yes I did think about that - I never told the US I was going for a vacation, I got the Visa from Russia after all.  But as I learned when I was there, US and Russia are two different countries :) That's good news and thanks for the expatriates link and I'll research there.